# Modify Windows Defender Firewall with Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-firewall

I'm still somewthat of a beginner with powershell and scripting so here's the issue I'm having: I'm trying to build a script that will modify the settings of a group of hosts to be compliant with NIST SP 800-53 and Block all Inbound traffic for all profiles in Windows Defender Firewall.

These hosts are **standalone machines** they are not joined to a domain.

I researched how to script this and on Microsfot's website it shows some scriplets using the `Set-NetFirewallProfile` command and the different parameters that can be used for the different profiles.
I wrote this script:

```
$fireWallPolicy = Set-NetFirewallProfile -Profile Private,Public,Domain -DefaultInboundAction Block -DefaultOutboundAction Block
if ($?) {
    Write-Host "Command executed successfully. `nWindows Firewall Profile status:" -ForegroundColor    Green
    Get-NetFirewallProfile -Profile Private,Public,Domain
} else {
    Write-Host "Command encountered an error"
}
```

I did a dry run and got some encouraging results with the debugging code I used to make sure the commands worked.
But when I checked the Win Defender Firewall GUI in Local Security Policy it didn't reflect the changes I made and when I scanned the system with an automated policy checker we use, it confirmed that none of the firewall changes I applied in script had an effect on the firewall and all the profiles were still set to Allow. I researched these issues and I found articles relating to the PolicyStore ActiveStore of the firewall policies and that some policies in the store are what control the Firewall master settings.

I ran `Get-NetfirewallProfile -PolicyStore ActiveStore` and it showed a similar status for the firewall but this time the status reflected what the GUI showed. So... my question is:

Has anyone had this issue before and if so, how can I use a script to actually change the Win Defender Firewall?

I tried modifying the script I showed above with different paramters to turn the firewall off with

Set-NetFirewallProfile -Profile Private,Public,Domain -Enabled False

But that also had no effect on the Windows Defender Firewall.

I was expecting the fire wall GUI in Local Security Policy under Windows Defender Firewall with Adanced Security to reflect the changes I applied in my script to...

```
$fireWallPolicy = Set-NetFirewallProfile -Profile Private,Public,Domain -DefaultInboundAction Block -DefaultOutboundAction Block
if ($?) {
    Write-Host "Command executed successfully. `nWindows Firewall Profile status:" -ForegroundColor    Green
    Get-NetFirewallProfile -Profile Private,Public,Domain
} else {
    Write-Host "Command encountered an error"
}
```

set the Private, Public, Domain profiles to  blocked, but they were all still set to allow. I believe that the `Set-NetFirewallProfile -Profile` cmdlet is not actually accessing the firewall MMC and I'm not sure how I can do that.

I also tried CMD commands `netsh advfirewall firewall` but I had the same issue.

Thank you in advance!

-Andrew

-NEW-

Good advice Martin, and I took some measures before I posted here to ensure some of those basics were already.
My setup right now with Powershell is:

- Running in an elevated prompt as an Administrator
- Loaded NetSecurity module in powershell
- Not domain-joined
- Running script on the host locally

This is where I am confused: when I run

`Set-NetFirewallProfile -Profile Public,Private,Domain -DefaultInboundAction Block -DefaultOutboundAction Block`

And check the status with

```
Get-NetFirewallProfile -Profile Public,Private,Domain
```

I get these results in powershell showing the firewall status:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9BlN.png
[Output with Get-NetFirewallProfile -Profile Public,Private,Domain][1]

But when I run

```
Get-NetFirewallProfile -PolicyStore ActiveStore
```

I get this
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOAUq.png
[Output with Get-NetFirewallProfile -PolicyStore ActiveStore][2]

I don't understand how using `Get-NetFirewallProfile -Profile Public,Private,Domain` shows me all the firewall profiles are blocked but using `Get-NetFirewallProfile -PolicyStore ActiveStore` shows they're all allowed.

This is the problem I'm having and I can't find a lot of information about it.

Comment: The machine are not in the same domain so what credentials are being used?  Can you remote login to the machines?  Most windows systems do not allow a remote login with username and password because the password is sent across the network unencrypted.  When you use Credentials to remote access a machine the password is encrypted, but for Credentials to work the local and remote machines have to be in the same domain.

Comment: Thank you for your response jdweng. These machines are standalone they are not domain-joined. And at the moment I’m not remoting into them, I’m running this script on one of the hosts directly while I’m building its image. I’m logged in as the primary user which has admin rights and I’m running my powershell script with elevated privileges. I hope this helps.

Comment: Try starting PS by right click on shortcut and select Run As Admin.

Comment: The Active Store is a subset of the Policy Store, that's why you're seeing inconsistent results. Check this and try to troubleshoot further: https://superuser.com/questions/1558202/how-to-determine-why-all-defender-firewall-profiles-are-active
There might be some group policy settings overriding your local firewall profile settings.

Answer (score 1):

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/operating-system-security/network-security/windows-firewall/configure-with-command-line?tabs=powershell

And: https://www.technewstoday.com/powershell-disable-firewall/

Somethings to note:

- First confirm you are running in an elevated prompt. Here is a quick way to confirm this:

```
if ($myWindowsPrincipal.IsInRole($adminRole))
{
    Write-Host "Running as Administrator."
}
else
{
    Write-Host "Not running as Administrator."
}
```

- Changes made using PowerShell might not be immediately reflected in the GUI. Are you restarting the machines after making these changes?
- Use `Get-NetFirewallProfile -PolicyStore ActiveStore` to confirm if the changes you've made applied
- Add some more error handling in the script to narrow down the issue.

Comment: I added my response to my original post. Thank you.